# London Bus Map app offline

Tags: uk, public-transport, london, buses, mobile-apps

I'm in London for 5 days and I'll travel with only tram&buses. I need to find an off-line app (Android || iPhone) which can display bus map; It would be a plus if I can plan a journey with it.

I've search on Google with no luck.

Comment: What about just downloading the PDF maps?: http://www.tfl.gov.uk/maps/bus

Comment: Doesn't look like it will be easy to plan a journey off those from a mobile phone screen. A Google search finds http://www.zuti.co.uk/Zuti_Maps/LondonBus/London_Bus.aspx but I have never used it.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity - why are you avoiding underground?

Comment: @AntiVeeranna In order to see london a little bit more :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @neubery commented, the London bus map is divided into [six reasonably sized spider-maps](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/maps/bus), namely,

1. [Central London Bus Map](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/central-london-bus-map.pdf)
2. [Central London Night Bus Map](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/central-london-night-bus-map.pdf)
3. [North-West London Bus Map](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/north-west-london-bus-map.pdf)
4. [North-East London Bus Map](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/north-east-london-bus-map.pdf)
5. [South-East London Bust Map](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/south-east-london-bus-map.pdf)
6. [South-West London Bust Map](http://www.tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/south-west-london-bus-map.pdf)

You could simply download the relevant PDFs on your phone, zoom in and plan your journey yourself. I use maps 1 and 2 myself and it's very well drawn! Although it might be a tad difficult to use on a mobile screen, these six PDFs do seem like a simple solution especially since you can search for text on them.